# How can I disable CPU throttling on MacBook pro 15 mid 2012 retina with new battery but died SMC?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance

MacBook Pro 15 mid-2012 Retina a1398
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

I have died SMC in my MBP with a new battery (I think it will solve problem of invisible battery for system), frequency of my i7 3635QM is 1,2GHz instead of the stated 2,4GHz.

Is there any solution that can return the declared processor frequency when the laptop is on charger?

UPD: The part of the SMC responsible for working with the battery has died.

[image: invisible battery]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  The translation is likely not accurate:   What do you mean by "died SMC in your MacBook Pro?"  Do you mean you *reset* it?  You also say you have a "new battery" but then reference an "invisible battery."  Is there a functional battery in your MacBook Pro?

Comment: If the SMC were "dead", the MBP would not function.

Comment: Regarding your update….assuming this to be true, there is nothing you can do.  You cannot bypass the SMC making this question moot.  Since your SMC can’t partially die, we still need details as initially requested